# How do I execute this find command multiple times throughout many directories with the ampersand '&' command?

Tags: bash, filesystems

writing a script that should utilize the find command (locate would not work because of some issue between the database and the filesystem, already tried and does not work) to locate a file by name or extension, but because the filesystem is about ~200TB, it would not be as fast and efficient to run a single find command. My idea is to run find through multiple directories with the '&' command as I believe it would be more efficient that way, although I my be wrong.
my current script so far is

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter either file name or format:"
read FileV

echo "Input the absolute path to directory"
read Dir

for d in $Dir
do
        ( cd $d && find ???
```

Comment: Hi, you're looking for FileV in Dir, is that correct?  Just clarifying what your goal is.  Tx

Comment: @KylieR. yes, fileV will be name or extension, I just planned on using FileV with wildcards

Comment: find $Dir -iname $FileV should work where FileV contains wildcards.  if that is too slow consider adding -type f (for files) and -size to specify size.  If you want to save the output do find $Dir -iname $FileV | /mydir/filetosaveto .  If searching within files, use grep. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xargs` to parallize the [find](/questions/tagged/find) command.  Run this in the top-level directory and it will farm out `find` commands to as many CPUs as it can.

One advantage of doing it this way is that since you're not backgrounding the processes, you wont need to worry about the jobspec output cluttering stdout.

Change the `-name` part to whatever you're looking for:

```
for dir in */; do echo "$dir"; done | xargs -P0 -I_ find _ -type f -name "*.sh" > /tmp/outfile
```

From the `xargs` manpage

> ```
>  -P max-procs, --max-procs=max-procs
>               Run up to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1.  If max-procs
>               is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible at a time.
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much this was exactly what I wanted to do. Also not to bother you more but is it possible for the output of the files to be printed into a text file after the code has ran? I am unsure about the syntax of it

Comment: @notaproatbash yes, that's very simple. I updated the answer, please accept it if it meets your expectations.

Comment: I see, i tried adding a > results.txt at the end of your xargs and for some reason it was 0 lines printed. this should work though, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck for the OP question is disk access. Given 200TB data size, only small part of the disk information will be in cached memory. As a result, the operation will be disk-bound. Running in parallel will have relatively little effect - the processes will be waiting for disk IO most of the time.

Following the proposals from other users - using locate, or similar is likely to provide more efficient search. Even a simple "Do It Youself" index - cron job that will do "find ...", and store the output in a file can be combined with grep to quickly find the files by name, and yield yield 100X speedup.

Answer (score 0):

To run one `find` instance per subdirectory in a path, you can use:

```
for d in "$Dir"/*/
do
  find "$d" -name "$FileV" &
done
wait
```

You may also want to consider installing and enabling `locate`, the standard file indexing and searching feature. It will periodically index all files, and then let you search through the index much faster than re-iterating all the files again.

Comment: So just to clarify, this will loop over for every directory without waiting for the previous to finish as well right? and I have tried the locate command on our EFS but i am not sure if that is possible after testing, do you also know any possible way around this? because i would definitely prefer locate as well.

Comment: I just tried this, it isnt granting permission at first but after i run it with sudo it doesnt give me any output, just a new command input line, any ideas?

Comment: It should have a `wait` at the end to avoid giving the impression that it's done when it's actually still searching. I've added that to the example. As for allowing `locate` to index your network fs, this depends on your `locate` implementation on your OS.